# Can I use same license key in multiple websites? JW Player

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6, jwplayer7

I have one JW Player Premium account. Can I use same license key in different/multiple websites. Or it is a violation ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a licensing problem, not a specific programming problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing instead of directly about programming. [[See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1402846)] for details and the [[help]] for more.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your specific license tier. Please contact support@jwplayer.com for information regarding your JW Player account.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that such a question can only be answered by the intellectual-property owners of JW Player Premium.  It's *their* license, after all.

Before presuming an answer to such a question, I suggest that you *ask* them, and that you print and file a dated copy *(on paper!)* of your request and of any response that you receive from them.  Contact them by various ways until you *get* an answer.

In any sort of commercial public situation, I suggest that you also ask your attorney for counsel on the matter.  (And I will take for granted that you *do* have corporate counsel ...)

**Do Not** assume(!) that anything(!!) "is okay," if there is even the slightest suspicion ... as is certainly true in this case ... that anyone else on Planet Earth might consider it to be "infringement."